# Re-locking BitLocker encrypted drive WITHOUT a drive letter

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption, bitlocker

The operating system is Windows 7 Enterprise.

I have an encrypted NTFS drive mounted at `C:\mount_point`. I successfully encrypted it with BitLocker GUI (in control panel) and can unlock it with password each time I need the files. However, I found that the GUI tool doesn't support re-locking (which is actually pretty stupid).

Then I found this: [Is it possible to re-lock a bitlocker drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/125982/is-it-possible-to-re-lock-a-bitlocker-drive) However, `manage-bde -lock` doesn't work with a drive without a drive letter. If I run `manage-bde -lock C:\mount_point`, it says "C:\mount_point is not understood. A drive letter is needed."

Thus, how should I re-lock my drive in this case, if I don't want to assign that drive a letter?

Comment: What do you gain from not assigning the volume a drive letter?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows allows me to do so, why cannot I just like it?

Comment: Toggle offline/online in Disk Management?

Comment: @TomYan that is a physical partition on my hdd. I don't think I can toggle the only hdd on my PC. Can I?

Comment: It's actually possible with `offline volume` in `diskpart`. You'll need to remove the path for the volume (e.g. with `mountvol /D`) first though. So I guess you can script a bit with them. Btw `manage-bde -lock PATH` works AT LEAST as of Windows 10 10586.

Answer (score 1):

You can try PowerShell as an elevated administrator:

```
Lock-BitLocker -MountPoint "C:\mount_point" -ForceDismount
```